# how to distribute space between multiple items

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add an image that covers the **top 20%** of the screen and the other **80%** should be a grid of cards. The image needs to be in the body and **not on the Appbar**. I made the grid of cards, and then I tried to put the image and the grid in a column. The implementation is the following.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        primary: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 4.0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
        title: Center(child: titleLogo,),
        ),
  //------------ PROBLEM BELOW ----------------
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            titleLogo,   //Image object
            TheGridView().build()  //Returns a GridView object
            ],
      ),
  ),
);
```

}

I am getting the following error

```
I/flutter (21751): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (21751): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (21751): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter (21751): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (21751): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (21751): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter (21751): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter (21751): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter (21751): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what `TheGridView().build` does? Seems very unidiomatic to me

Comment: `TheGridView()` is a class  and `TheGridView.build()` returns a **GridView** object whose each grid element is a **card** object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for distributing space between multiple items you should use the [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget like this:

```
return new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    new Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: new Container(//use your Gridview instead 
        color: Colors.green,
      )
    )
  ],

);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! @Raouf Rahiche. This fixed it.